# How to change the creation time of files based on filenames using AppleScript or Automator?

Tags: applescript, automator

I have a folder containing thousands of picture files. Each filename starts as YYYY-MM-DD. The Date Created field only sometimes matches the date in the filename. I would like to accomplish this for each picture file:

If YYYY-MM-DD of filename does not match Date Created, then set Date Created to YYYY-MM-DD of filename and set Time Created to 11:11:11 (HH:MM:SS).

How exactly can I do this?  FYI, I’m on a Mac mini and OS X 10.9 and have been spinning my wheels.  Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

You could use a shell command like this:

`for f in *; do if [[ $(date -jf %s $(stat -f%B "$f") +%F) != ${f:0:10} ]]; then SetFile -d ${f:5:2}/${f:8:2}/${f:0:4} "$f"; mtime=$(GetFileInfo -m "$f"); SetFile -m "${mtime:0:10} 11:11:11" "$f"; fi; done`

SetFile and GetFileInfo are part of the developer tools package that can be downloaded from Xcode's preferences or from http://developer.apple.com/downloads/.

In the date command, -j disables setting the time, -f specifies a format string, and %F is a format like 2013-12-31. stat -f specifies a format string and %B is creation (birth) time. In GetFileInfo and SetFile, -m is the modification time and -d is the creation time.

Comment: Thanks so much for your response Lri, but with my limited Apple experience I find it difficult to follow.  How might I accomplish this task with just Automator and maybe some Applescript, or is Xcode absolutely necessary?