# Change Creation Date and Time based on filename in using Mac Terminal

Tags: ios, date, terminal

I have thousands of old dv video files, al with wrong creation dates, but each filename has date and time like this;

`2001-12-22 00;52;40.dv   YYYY-MM-DD HH;MM;SS.dv`

There was a similar problem posted 6 years ago, but only with year month date in the file name, so he wanted the time fixed at 11:11:11.

I would like to have some help to include the time from the file name also.

This is the code from the previous post:

```
for f in *.*; do if [[ $(date -jf %s $(stat -f%B "$f") +%F) != ${f:0:10} ]]; then SetFile -d ${f:5:2}/${f:8:2}/${f:0:4} "$f"; mtime=$(GetFileInfo -m "$f"); SetFile -m "${mtime:0:10} 11:11:11" "$f"; fi; done
```

[Link from 6 years ago](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19731480/how-to-change-the-creation-time-of-files-based-on-filenames-using-applescript-or)

This code sets the right date, but for the time it uses the day and month from the file name, like this; Created 22 December 2001 at 12:22, and Modified 10 April 2011 at 11:11, remains unchanged with the date but got the time 11:11.

Only the Created date and time are important though, and dont need to check if dates are different.

I have installed Xcode and exiftool.

There was also another post 9 months ago, but I could not get it to work (I am a Terminal beginner).

```
for i in *.*; do SetFile -d "${x:4:2}/${x:6:2}/${x:0:4} ${x:9:2}:${x:11:2}:${x:13:2}" "$i" done
```

**UPDATE** I figured out the problem with the code suggested 9 months ago, not using the same variable for the loop and in the brackets. for i in... {x:4:2} should be for i in... {i:4:2} at least on Mac and finish with a semicolon before done.

```
for i in *.*; do SetFile -d "${i:4:2}/${i:6:2}/${i:0:4}:${i:9:2}:${i:11:2}:${i:13:2}" "$i"; done
```

[Change Date and Time of Creation and Modification of file based on filename in MacOS folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59273834/change-date-and-time-of-creation-and-modification-of-file-based-on-filename-in-m)

Problem solved :-)